# tampermonkey getting button by style instead of class or ID

Tags: tampermonkey

How would I go about checking if this is is active:

When its not active its just

The "style" is the part that makes it "active" and visible on screen.   Is there a way that I can get the Jump button by that style inside the div?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the element has a `style` attribute by putting `[style]` in a selector:

```
if (document.querySelector('#jump[style]')) {
  console.log('style attribute exists on jump element');
} else {
  console.log('style attribute doesn\'t exist');
}
```